# My Mac disconnects all USB devices connected via my Blackmagic EGPU (Thunderbolt)

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

My intel macbook sometime randomly disconnects all USB devices that are connected through the black magic eGPU. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the thunderbolt connection as my multi-monitor setup doesn't get impacted.

I tried debugging this but can't see any errors in the dmesg log that would indicate a fault. What's a good way to debug this and get a root cause? This only started happening after the Monterey update.

Comment: See if there is a driver at Blackmagic.com support, especially if this happened immediately after a major OS update.

Comment: no new drivers since a long time unfortunately

Comment: Our videographers use lots of Blackmagic Design hardware in their studios and in the field. They say Support can be pretty helpful. Why don't you write to them here: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/contact/email